# How to run a specific test in testng

Tags: maven, testing, selenium

I am trying to run a unique test from testng.xml.My testng.xml is as below:

```
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="one">
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
  <parameter name="os" value="win"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.snapdeal.qa.Tests.MyAccount.SignUpTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="two">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
  <parameter name="os" value="win"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.snapdeal.qa.Tests.MyAccount.BaseTest"/>
      <class name="com.snapdeal.qa.Tests.MyAccount.SignUpTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

I am using maven and i am passing which test to run through sure-fire like this:
test -Dtests="one"
But its running all tests defined in testng.Where is actually i am wrong. and how to run a specfic test like this in any way

Comment: do you mean you want to run test one by one? from xml?

Answer (score 0):

Code should be like below if you want to run only 1 test from xml :

```
  <suite name="Suite">
    <test name="one">
         <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
         <parameter name="os" value="win"/>
       <classes>
          <class name="yourpackagename.yourclasname"/>
       </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Just use test which you want to run like above. Pass package name and class name which you want to run.

If you want to skip specific test then you can set like : **@Test(enabled = false)** in yout java class file. So testNG will not run that test. So set (enabled = false) for test which you do not want to run.

Comment: actually we want to keep all test configuration and then we want to run only one test from testng by just passing the parameter Is it possible

Comment: Yes you can set @Test(enabled = false) set enabled = false for all tests which you do not want to run. see I have updated answer.